# I've met a few of teachers who use **guess** a lot. why do they do that?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/RnJJqfu6i8U?t=98) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> Let's look at the first sentence, which is an example. "The bill was split between Frank
>   and Mark." **guess** We have two people,

most of words comes from the official transcript except for one, the word **guess** which is added by me.

I've met a few of teachers who use **guess** a lot. why do they do that?

Comment: She doesn't say 'guess' - I think it's 'OK' before going on to the explanation, but swallowed so that it's barely audible, which is why it isn't included in the transcript.

Comment: I hear it as “Okay so we have two people …”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a verbal habit.  It means "I suppose that...". Perhaps it comes from a kind of modesty  "I want to tell you my opinion, but I don't want to force it on you."

People do develop their own habits in speech. Some people start lots of sentences with "So...". I knew one person who said "Well, basically..." whenever they explained something (even when it was very complex).  They are just habits and don't have any great meaning.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful. Just for double confirmation, is "guess" the verbal habit of that presenter discussed in OP?

Comment: I haven't seen the presenter. I can't tell if he says "guess" or "okay" or if it is a transcription error. Comments suggest it is an error.